# How to Handle JSON Responses with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, flickr

I am making a call to the FlickR API based on a search term that a user enters in an editText. The result is going to be several JSON objects (or at least that is what I am aiming for), which I ultimately want to display in a GridView.

Right now, I know that I am making a successful call to the FlickR API since I am firing the onResponse method of Retrofit. However, I am unsure how to view the raw response data to display in a gridview:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mSearchTerm;
private Button mRequestButton;
private String mQuery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSearchTerm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ediText_search_term);
    mRequestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request_button);
    mRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mQuery = mSearchTerm.getText().toString();
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/")
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();


            ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<List<Photo>> call = apiInterface.getPhotos(mQuery);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Photo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Photo>> call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Photo>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }
    });



}

//Synchronous vs. Asynchronous
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("?&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=<Ali>&api_key=1c448390199c03a6f2d436c40defd90e&format=json")  //
    Call<List<Photo>> getPhotos(@Query("q") String photoSearchTerm);
   }

}
```

Comment: If you want a list of photos, wouldn't you want a `Call<List<Photo>>`? Once you have that, it's just a matter of putting your Photo objects into an Adapter and putting into a GridView

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I guess I also need to know how I map the JSON responses from FlickR to a POJO? I am having difficulty seeing the JSON view of the photos when I browse the FlickR website....

Comment: I don't know what the JSON you get back looks like, but the Gson converter for Retrofit should already handle that POJO stuff for you.

Comment: use 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0' depedency to log your retrofit response,so that u can generate pojo object from that json response.

Comment: Hi, check this repo with example usage of Retrofit2 https://github.com/MrOnyszko/Retrofit2Sample It'll help you with Retrofit.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will give it all a shot and let you know.

Comment: All - I have updated my code and now have a new issue, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987265/nosuchmethoderror-when-trying-to-log-retrofit-json-response?noredirect=1#comment65327188_38987265

Comment: All - thanks again for your help. I have updated the code but am now trying to figure out how to incorporate the editText variable (mQuery) so that it is the search term used in the FlickR API cal....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Retrofit + Picasso to retrieve the photo and fetch it into the adapter

http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/android-retrofit-images-tutorial/